# MATLAB Out of Memory when using perl()

Tags: matlab, perl, memory

I've got a perl script that I want to execute using MATLAB using the perl() function, and it keeps giving me a "System error: Out of memory!", which seems to be from perl.

My perl script needs about 5GB of memory to run, and it works fine when run through Cygwin. How do i get MATLAB to give perl more memory?

Comment: How much RAM do you have? If you have Unix version, you can disable JVM on matlab launch to save yourself a whole load of RAM.

Comment: It is not MATLAB giving the memory. Most likely MATLAB+perl are more than the memory you have.

Comment: I've got 24 gigs. The perl script runs fine when using perl on command line.

Comment: I look at my task manager, and the memory graph barely goes up before it throws the error.

Comment: But do you have more things in MATLAB? Run the code to before you carl PERL and check your memory

Comment: I think this might be your JVM heap space rather than your machine's physical RAM

Comment: Is it a 32-bit Perl? That can only access 4 GiB of memory (of which 1 or 2 GiB is reserved by the OS).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MATLAB ships with the 32 bit version of perl. That's why it couldn't run.